# Compute the following Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm trying to Laplace transform the function
\begin{equation}
|\theta(t)|\sin(l\theta(t)),
\end{equation}
where $\theta(t)$ is any function of t.
I want to express the result with $\tilde{\theta}(s)$, the Laplace transform of $\theta$:
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\theta}(s) = \int \theta(t)e^{-st} dt.
\end{equation}

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: without further knowledge of $\theta(t)$ there is no way to proceed.